# ExecuteSqlRawAsync returns -1 in Entity Framework 3.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In my **ASP.NET Core 3.1**  web application, I am mostly using stored procedures. When using `ExecuteSqlRawAsync` in **Entity Framework Core** it always returns `-1`. Below given is my generalized method to execute stored procedures.

```
  public async Task<int> ExecuteSqlNonQuery(string StoredProcName, params object[] parameters)
  {
        int iTotalRecordsAffected = 0;

        List<TEntity> listOfObject = null;

        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(StoredProcName))
            {
                StringBuilder sbStoredProc = new StringBuilder();
                sbStoredProc.Append("Exec ");
                sbStoredProc.Append(StoredProcName);

                if (parameters != null)
                {
                    foreach (SqlParameter item in parameters)
                    {
                        if (listOfObject == null)
                        {
                            sbStoredProc.Append(" @");
                            listOfObject = new List<TEntity>();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sbStoredProc.Append(", @");
                        }
                        sbStoredProc.Append(item.ParameterName.Replace("@", ""));
                        if (item.Direction == System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output)
                        {
                            sbStoredProc.Append(" OUT");
                        }
                    }
                }

                iTotalRecordsAffected = await _DBContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(sbStoredProc.ToString(), parameters);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            if (_DBContext.Database.GetDbConnection().State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                _DBContext.Database.GetDbConnection().Close();
            }
        }

        return iTotalRecordsAffected;
 }
```

Here is my controller method that calls a SP to update data.

```
   public async Task<int> UpdateCustomerData(EditCustomerDetail editCustomerDetail)
    {
        int iTotalRecordsEffected = 0;

        try
        {
            List<SqlParameter> sqlParamList = new List<SqlParameter>()
            {
                new SqlParameter("@CustomerID",editCustomerDetail.CorporateID),
                new SqlParameter("@CustomerName",editCustomerDetail.CorporateName),
                new SqlParameter("@CustomerAddress",editCustomerDetail.Address),
                new SqlParameter("@City",editCustomerDetail.City),
                new SqlParameter("@CountryID",editCustomerDetail.CountryID),
                new SqlParameter("@StateID",editCustomerDetail.StateID),
                new SqlParameter("@Description",editCustomerDetail.Description),
                new SqlParameter("@Phone",editCustomerDetail.Phone),
                new SqlParameter("@Fax",editCustomerDetail.Fax),
                new SqlParameter("@ModifiedBy",editCustomerDetail.UserID)
            };

            iTotalRecordsEffected = await _unitOfWork.GetRepository<EditCustomerDetail>().ExecuteSqlNonQuery("UpdateCustomerDetails", sqlParamList.ToArray());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {

        }
        return iTotalRecordsEffected;
    }
```

Any suggestion what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This seems to be the standard behavior of ADO.NET [ExecuteNonQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.8#remarks). EF Core is this case is just an intermediator.

Comment: @IvanStoev I found the problem ::-  When SET NOCOUNT ON is set on the connection the rows affected by individual statements stop contributing to the count of rows affected that is returned by this method. This solve my problem.